# Convert column values to row values

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

```
  **uid         pid    mail   value**

     1          78     27     Nairobi

     2          78     27     Milimani

     3          78     27     Criminal

     4          78     27     1427932800
```

I have a DB table above and only need the 'value' column values. I want to have the column values display in rows (not comma separated) for a cross-tab report. my ideal result would be:

```
        **Nairobi  Milimani  Criminal  1427932800**
```

The matching 'pid' and 'mail' means that the corresponding 'value' is from a single submission and a change in pid and mail (not captured here) is a new submission!

so how do I write an sql for converting the 'value' column values to row values?
any help much appreciated.

'Pivot' has not really helped or i'm probably doing it wrongly.!!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: So if someone inserts one additional row, you'll suddenly have 5 columns?!?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert column values to rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278908/convert-column-values-to-rows)

Comment: @polycarproyal  Why would you ask the same question twice on a same day?

Answer (score 0):

In *SQL-Server* you can use `PIVOT`.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    [uid] INT,
    pid INT,
    mail INT,
    value NVARCHAR(60)
)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES 
(1,          78,     27,     'Nairobi'),
(2,          78,     27,     'Milimani'),
(3,          78,     27,     'Criminal'),
(4,          78,     27,     '1427932800')
```

This is example of `STATIC PIVOT`:

```
SELECT [Nairobi], [Milimani], [Criminal], [1427932800]
FROM (
    SELECT value
    FROM #Test
) x
PIVOT
(
MAX(value)
FOR value in ([Nairobi], [Milimani], [Criminal], [1427932800])
) piv
DROP TABLE #Test
```

And this is example of `DYNAMIC PIVOT`:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(value) 
                    FROM #test
                    GROUP BY value, [pid]
                    ORDER BY [pid]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                SELECT value
                FROM #test
            ) x
            PIVOT
            (
                MAX(value)
                FOR value IN (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```